# Tomcat not recognizing cpho.html and hhpnz.html file as an index.html file

Tags: angular, tomcat7

I am running two application in one Angular project, what I want is to run the apps in a Tomcat server. My problem is when I try to build it and put the dist folder in the Tomcat, it is not recognizing the cpho.html and hhpnz.html as an index.html file even though I try to set it up as an index.html in the .angular-cli.json, any solution? work around? or maybe even a better way to do this?

Here is my [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpxp5.png)

Here is my .angular-cli.json, [cpho](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZg5u.png), and for [hhpnz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsABn.png)

Comment: would it be possible for you to split up your project?
and use the common things as dependency? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152331/how-to-setup-angular-project-as-a-dependency-in-package-json-of-another-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not really understand your question,

but speaking of Tomcat, `index.html` has special treatment as a "welcome file" (the file that is returned when a client makes request for a directory containing this file).

The list of welcome file names is configurable in Web application descriptor file (`WEB-INF/web.xml`). The details are in the [Servlet specification](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Specifications#Java_Servlet_Specifications).

The default configuration is the following:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: What i did is add my 2 index.html file (cpho.html & hhpnz.html) in the welcome-file-list, but I'm wondering if it's the right way to do it? Now i;m starting to think maybe do what @Axel M says like try to split the project up and use the common things as dependency.

Comment: If it is your own `WEB-INF/web.xml` it is OK to configure it how it best suits your web application. (A common mistake is to start modifying the files in Tomcat's conf/ directory. Those are the defaults shared by all applications). From a philosophical point of view, I think I would prefer to rename the files to 'index.html'.

Comment: BTW, [Cool URIs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI) - an article on design of URLs.

Comment: but the problem I'm having if I put it back in the index.html name is that there will be 2 of them (cpho.html and hhpnz.html) in the src folder.