# Is it possible to check if an Angular library is available at runtime?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating an [Angular library](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) - let's call it **libA** - that can use another Angular library - let's call it **libB** - for an optional feature, i.e., if the Angular **application** doesn't have the **libB**, the feature in the **libA** will be disabled. But, if the Angular app has the **libB** installed, the feature in **libA** will be available.

So, to implement this behavior, I'd have to make verifications in **libA** to check if **libB** is available. However, I'm having trouble verifying whether or not the **libB** is installed in the application.

Does anyone know how can I check if the **libB** is installed in the application inside **libA**?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/#using-peer-dependencies 
Recommendation: Use as a dependency not as a direct install.

Comment: Thanks, @Numichi. but how can **libA** know if the **libB** is available?

Answer (score 0):

projects/libA/package.json

```
{
    "name": "libA",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "peerDependencies": {
        "libB": "0.0.0",
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "tslib": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "publishConfig": {
        "registry": "http://192.168.10.20:4873"
    }

}
```

And main package configuration see it (example): [How to setup angular project as a dependency in package.json of another angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152331/how-to-setup-angular-project-as-a-dependency-in-package-json-of-another-angular)

**My solution is**
(IP is a example)

I run a own registry (example: https://verdaccio.org/) on one Linux VM (exist docker too) and I upload my package into this.
Every package set:

```
{
    "name": "@my-name/package-name",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "peerDependencies": {
       ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "tslib": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "publishConfig": {
        "registry": "http://192.168.10.20:4873"
    }
}
```

```
$ ng build <package-name>
$ cd /path/to/dist/package-name
$ npm publish
```

**In Angular project**

```
$ npm login --scope=@my-name --registry=http://192.168.10.20:4873/
$ npm install @my-name/package-name
```

(I used many configuration to set registry, so maybe login not enough. I not tracked it. :D)